# date_select throws an exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When the application locale is set to :he, the following auto-generated code throws an exception:

```
undefined method `map' for "translation missing: he.date.order":String

<%= f.date_select :birthday %>
```

I double checked and not only the locales for Hebrew and English are identical (key-wise), the English locale files does not include en.date.order.

Where can this exception stem from?

I'm using `Ruby 2` with `Rails 4`.

**Edit:**
Solution:

```
he:
  date: #Throws an exception otherwise.
    order:
      - "year"
      - "month"
      - "day"
```

Comment: What does `I18n.translate('date.order')` respond? Using `en` locale it responds `["year", "month", "day"]`, maybe using `he` locale it doesn't respond an array

Comment: Thanks! It works! I wonder, where is `date.order` defined?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `he.yml` listed [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale)? it seems to have `date.order`, so you shouldn't need to specify it by yourself

Comment: I wasn't aware of such list, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps post solution instead of editing post, to close this issue.

Comment: passing an option like `order: ['year']` will resolve this issue if you dont want to put in locale file